# Cordova playback-only media plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

My Cordova 3.4 application uses the media plugin for playback only. But adding org.apache.cordova.media automatically requests permission for recording audio and accessing external storage. I'd like to remove those unnecessary permissions. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try the Low Latency Audio plugin at plugreg.com.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. The com.phonegap.LowLatencyAudio API is quite different from the regular Media plugin, i'll switch to this if i can't find a workaround with the current plugin.

Answer (score 4):

After you installed the media plugin go into the "plugins" directory within your cordova project. Edit two files and remove the permissions there:

1) android.json
2) org.apache.cordova.media/plugin.xml

When you make a new build with cordova - permissions should not get added anymore.

UPDATE: But its just a workaround ... if you de/install any plugins again, you may have to edit files again.

Answer (score 4):

I've forked the official Apache media plugin and just removed those permissions. Part of my build process now involves running the command that points to my forked repository:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/webnard/cordova-plugin-media.git#playback-only`

Comment: do you need PHONE_STATE permissions to play back media in foreground mode?

Comment: Just forked your fork and removed PHONE_STATE - seems to work fine given my need is foreground playback only. The problem with phone_state is its an overarching permission that seems to allow a low of phone details  which is freaking out my users

Comment: hmm where to run this command or what to add to the config file instead?